# is there any way to get user request's internal ip address in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ip

There is two type if IP address.

Internal - that we can get using `ipconfig`
External - that we can check using google what is my IP

I want to read requested user's internal IP address. I am using `express-ip` module to get the IP address.

```
const expressip = require('express-ip');
app.use(expressip().getIpInfoMiddleware);
```

then I can check the user's **external** IP address `req.ipInfo`

```
const ip = req.ipInfo.ip || '';
```

How can I read internal IP address? is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need the internal IP of the user? You could get it but usually through shenanigans that leak the IP more by an accident than design.

Comment: to identify the actual user from the organization who is chatting, how can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think it's possible. The internal IP address is internal to your network, and therefore is not exposed over the internet.